# TortoiseSVN -> how to find Working copy assigned to REPO

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, repo, working-copy

I have TortoiseSVN in use. I have a REPO but I don`t know which working copy is assigned to it.

**How can I find out which working copy is assigned to my REPO ?**

Since I don`t know how to use the command line commands, is there a way to do it oterwise?

Answer (score 1):

- If you know location of your WC on drive

`cd <WC-DIR>`

`svn info`

and check value of key `Repository Root` for [svn info](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.info.html) output

- If

1. Your SVN-client is reasonable fresh (have single `.svn` folder inside root of WC, not ".svn-per-folder")
2. You don't know *are any* WCes and *there they are*

you still can use some command-line tricks (outside of SVN CLI)

```
dir /AD /N /S *.svn. | find "Directory"
```

will show you all dirs below you current root, which are (can be) Working Copies of SVN-repos. You have just `cd` and repeat `svn info` in every folder (by hand or after easy authomation of this task)